# как сделать, чтобы после ответа пользователя появлялся следующий вопрос и считало количество правильных ответов? Для тг бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Не могу понять как сделать в тг боте, чтобы пользователь вводил свой ответ в чат бота и сам бот считал количество правильных ответов, и после опроса появлялся текст с выводом, можете пожалуйста подсказать как это сделать?

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def text(message):
score = 0
if message.text == "/start":
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Привет, я бот по профориентации, я помогу тебе выбрать будущую профессию надеюсь ты справишься!!! Введи /test чтобы начать тест.  ')
elif message.text == "/test":
    for question in questions:
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, text)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, question.vopros, reply_markup = keyboard)
        otvet = readchar.readchar()
        if otvet == question.otvet:
            score += 1
   
bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: Мне просто интересно, а этот код вы где взяли?

Comment: Я его сам писал

Comment: Используй fsm: записывай ответы и веди пользователя по цепочке вопросов

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py

Comment: CausonQ, это для библиотеки aiogram, а я пишу на библиотеки telebot